# Два самых не/романтичных человека — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, прилагательные, частица-не

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В проспекте написано: *два самых **не романтичных** человека.*

Я думаю, что нужно писать слитно. А как правильно? Объясните, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Вы правы, *неромантичные* здесь можно заменить синонимом *приземлённые,* лишённые романтики, к тому же есть слово, выражающее степень качества - *самые,* следовательно, слитно.

Есть здесь и пунктуационная ошибка.

Океан нашепчет им мелодию любви(,) и где(,) как не в Городе Ангелов(,) поверить в настоящую любовь. Первая запятая должна разделить простые предложения в сложном, а вторая и третья - выделить союзный оборот *где, как не...*